# Multi-file processing for loop JSON to appended CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, for-loop

I am having trouble with the correct syntax of a for loop to open several gzip lines json files one at a time, process the files to extract only certain key value pairs and then save to an appended single csv file. The gzip files are large.

How should the for loop nest to open, process, write one file at a time?

I either seem to open/load all files at once before writing, then eventually crash memory or successfully open 1 at a time but I/O error at the write stage because the outfile has been closed.

```
directory = r"*/mydirectory*"

field_names = [
    "id",
    "created_at",
    "user_screen_name",
    "text",
    "lang",
    "place_country_code",
    "place_name",
    "coordinates",
    "entities_user_mentions_screen_name",
]

tweets = []

for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if filename.path.endswith(".gz") and filename.is_file():
        with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as infile, \
             open('clean_tweet_all_data.csv', 'a', newline="", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                tweets.append(json.loads(line)),
                csv_output = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=",", fieldnames=field_names,
                                            extrasaction="ignore")
                if outfile.tell() == 0:
                    csv_output.writeheader(),
                    csv_output.writerows(get_arrays(entry) for entry in tweets)


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The function `get_arrays(entry)` flattens the json files so the `field_names` list is used to select the key value pairs is working well.

Comment: Just open the `outfile` once before the outer-most `for`, write the header, and then write the rows to it as necessary in the nested `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues I see, though I don't know if this causes the issue you are describing

1. The `tweets` list just keeps growing, which might cause memory error, you should reset it (`tweets = []`) after you finish writing the tweet
2. There is no need for the `infile.close()` and `outfile.close()` at the end, this is already taken care of by the context manager (`with open ...`)
3. You are only writing to the file once, since you are only writing if `outfile.tell() == 0`, maybe you meant to put the last line outside of the `if` block?

Comment: FWIW, #2 is allowed even though unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick relies, I tried to incorporate yours and @martineau comments and moved the 'open outfile' and 'writeheader' lines to before the loop. No errors but it seems to do the same thing by creating the outfile and writing the header then files the memory with all the infile lines without writing until VSC crashes. I used 'tweets.clear()' for 1. is that correct? Sorry for noob question.

Comment: I guess I can't add the new code block here?

Comment: @Mugwuffin: You guessed correctly, comments are not a place for code blocks, which is **in** questions (and answers).